# Is "who are doing the dishes?" an acceptable question?

Tags: grammatical-number, questions, who

If you know 2 people are doing the dishes, can you say "who are doing the dishes?" or would it always be "who is?"

Comment: You could bypass the issue by asking “The dishes are being done by whom?“

Answer (score 8):

It's an inconsistency in the language that both "Mary is doing the dishes" and "Mary and John are doing the dishes" become "Who is doing the dishes?" I presume this is because the person asking is nearly always completely ignorant of the answer (the number of people doing the dishes; his, her, or their names). To a native, "who are" sounds wrong.

On the other hand, if you know two or more people are doing the dishes, but you don't know which two, you could ask, "Which people are doing the dishes?" In this case you are requesting someone specify / add information.

Comment: This answer is correct for the USA. I wonder whether it's also correct in England or other places.

Comment: Sounds good to me (UK).

Comment: Ditto for me (also UK).

Comment: Ditto for me (Australia).

Comment: I agree that the plural is rarely used as such by native speakers, but I believe that formally the construction is indeed grammatical, and, as previously suggested, expresses a prior belief that multiple individuals would satisfy the response. Yet the lack of use and the resulting awkwardness to the native speaker are reason enough to avoid. Also note, no problem occurs in "Who are *the ones* doing the dishes?", even though the difference is exceedingly slight. Indeed, this form is merely a more verbose version of the original.